# Limit PHP-FPM to one execution on a time

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I would like to limit `PHP-FPM` to execute only once at a given time,
which means any further request will be queued.

I'm using `nginx` but I think it's a matter of `PHP-FPM` configuration.

I read about `PHP-FPM` `listen.backlog` and `process.max`,
it looked for me that process.max is what I need to tune but I wasn't sure..

What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I only use PHP for files processing, so it needs to be limited in order to protect the server from hige CPU usage

Comment: Then why are you running it via a webserver? This makes no sense. Use a message queue or a single threaded daemon or a batch process.

Comment: I'm running `nginx` and serve primarily static files, when needed I'm allowing users to upload their own files (not executable) via `PHP-FPM`

Comment: You can limit the number of requests per second/minute via nginx: https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

Comment: @abler98 I'm trying to avoid CPU usage not limiting the rate..

Comment: You are going about the wrong way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it the XY problem

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?
I already have `nginx` for my web-server why sould I use something else?

Comment: I do like this question. Perhaps not the best approach for the case in the question, but I was looking for this to provide an interface to wake my server from a raspberry pie with minimal memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

You're right. Just set these parameters:

```
pm = static
pm.max_children = 1
```

But maybe you need a locking mechanism? In this case you can try using some of this:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-acquire.php

https://symfony.com/doc/current/lock.html